# Generating HTML

Tags: html, c

```
     <form action=post ...>
     //...
     <td><select name="data">
        <option value="1" $isSelected_1>1</option>
                    //....100 options...
        <option value="148" $isSelected_100>100</option>
         </select>
    </td>
    //...
```

I'm generating html inside a C program. However, I need to check the options selected or unselected and I think its bad to create 100 variables(also many if statements...). What could be the best solution?

Comment: Uh, a loop?  Please be more specific about what you don't know how to do, because right now this sounds like a programming 101 question.

Comment: Option values are not same for each one, so looping does not solve my problem.

Comment: @ thetux4 you could use multiple arrays, or some kind of object/struc. I'm not all that familiar with c so I'm not sure what all is available.

Answer (score 3):

an array, and loop?
psuedo code:

```
a[1] = true;
...
a[n] = false;

for(i = 1 -> n)
 <option value='i'+(a[i] ? selected : '')>...
```

Answer (score 3):

From your question, it's a little difficult to know what you are trying to do. If you are just needing to store 100 options and check which ones are selected, you could store the results in an array and then loop over them using for and take appropriate action.

With that said, I wouldn't use C for this unless I had no other option. If you have the option, you should really use a language with has better string support and which manages memory for you. A good example would be something like Perl, Python, or *anything but C*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `arrays, loops or even structures

```
struct variables{
 //your variables
 }
```

or

```
int variables[100]={/*your variable stuffs*/}
```

that should work!
and you could probably use Javascript for that.